# jackson-dataformat-csv parsing complex mapping in header field names

Tags: java, csv, jackson-dataformat-csv

I'm using the CSV parsing utilities from `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv`. Minimum Java 8.

Let's say I have a POJO as such:

```
class MyPojo {
    @JsonProperty("Object ID")
    private String objectName;

    // ... other basic fields here

    private Map<String, String> customFields;
    private Map<String, String> mapOfPoints;
}
```

And a CSV file like this:

```
Object ID,Point 1,Point 2, Point 3,Point 4,Custom Field 1,Another Custom Field
abc123,1.00;1.00,1.00;-1.00,-1.00;1.00,-1.00;-1.00,something,more of something
```

Assuming the basic fields that line up to POJO fields with `@JsonProperty` are parsed fine.

1. Is it possible to have any data field matching a header that starts with `Point` to be sent to the `mapOfPoints` map (I'll parse the actual point data later with something else), where the key is the header name? So the first data row will have a `Point 1` key in the `mapOfPoints` map, with a value of `1.00;1.00`.
2. Further, can I have it so that any field not handled by the `JsonProperty` annotations and that isn't taken care of by question #1 (so, starting with `Point`) to go to the customFields map? So in the data row above, there would be a `customFields` map entry of key `Custom Field 1` and value `something`.